# Heap space out of memory error in javafx project maven

Tags: java, maven, javafx, memory, out-of-memory

I wrote my research project using javafx and maven. When I'm trying run some function,  I get error out of memory. I solved this problem in usually console project, but I can't solve the problem in maven.

I checked using memory in task manager and I got information, that my program uses about 2.5-3.0 Gb memory. Maven's app don't give me more than 2gb memory. How to fix this?

I used  environment variables, 
configuration in pom.xml:

```
<configuration><argLine>-Xmx4098m</argLine></configuration>
```

and this

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>-Xmx4098m</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Maybe I used this incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute below command before running application

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4098m -Xmx4098m  -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary"
```